# Filter and sort datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have created an item list in which all items are loaded, and I need to filter the data according to the text entered in the textbox.
Please guide me how to filter and sort data, I have created the fallowing code

```
 Private Sub loadsearchitems(item As String)
    dgvsearchitem.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical
    On Error Resume Next
    con = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    con.Open()
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet
    Dim adapter As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

    sqlstr = "SELECT Imaster.icode, Imaster.iname & '  ' & MfgComTab.comname as[Iname], Imaster.unitcode, Imaster.tax,Unit.unitname FROM ((Imaster INNER JOIN MfgComTab ON Imaster.mccode = MfgComTab.mccode) INNER JOIN Unit ON Imaster.unitcode = Unit.unitcode) WHERE (Imaster.isdeleted = 'N') AND Imaster.comcode=@comcode AND Imaster.iname like '%' & @item & '%'   order by iname asc  "

    adapter.SelectCommand = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlstr, con)
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comcode", compcode)
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iname", item)

    adapter.Fill(ds)
    If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then

        dgvsearchitem.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

        dgvsearchitem.Columns("unitname").Visible = False
        dgvsearchitem.Columns("unitcode").Visible = False
        dgvsearchitem.Columns("icode").Visible = False
        dgvsearchitem.Columns("tax").Visible = False
        dgvsearchitem.Columns("Iname").Width = 371
    Else
        ds.Dispose()

    End If
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

But in the above code the application is slow because every time any text is entered a query is executed. Please tell me any solution where query is executed only once and when we enter the text it only search the items by wild card and filter it.

Comment: Did you initially set the DataSource with the same query but without the WHERE condition?

Comment: no . when the text box is blank it loads all the records and when i enters the text it filters but slowdown the form.

Comment: If you want to load data once and reuse it, you need to use `DataView` for filter and sort. So, you need to separate logic of filtering and loading data. You can use default view or create your own. Your datasource will maintain all records but by applying filters to data view you will only display subsets of datasource records

Comment: please share any example ..

Comment: You can get example using Data view from MSDN - I gave you the direction. Ah - there is an answer --> below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you initially set the DataGridView with all the records, then you could avoid to go again to the database to extract your data in a filtered way. You have already extracted everything, so you could simply set the DataSource with a [DataView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/System.Data.DataView(v=vs.100).aspx) filtered locally

```
 ' Code that loads initially the grid
  sqlstr = "SELECT Imaster.icode, Imaster.iname .....FROM ...." ' NO WHERE HERE
  ....
  dgvsearchitem.DataSource = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView
```

Now in your  `loadsearchitems` instead of executing again a query against the database you could take the datasource and set the [RowFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.100).aspx) property

```
 Dim v as DataView = CType(dgvsearchitem.DataSource, DataView)
 v.RowFilter = "Imaster.comcode='" & compcode & "' AND Imaster.iname like '%" & item & "'%'"
```

Note how the `RowFilter` property doesn't understand the use of parameters, so if it is possible for your `comcode` field to contain single quotes you need to add a some form of doubling the quotes (a String.Replace will do) to avoid a syntax error. And yes, there is no worry for Sql Injection on a DataView (it is a disconnected object and whatever your user types in the compcode field it cannot reach the database)

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataTable' to type 'System.Data.DataView'. the above error is comming

Comment: Did you assign a DataView as explained in the first part? If you assign a DataTable then you will get this error. _dgvsearchitem.DataSource = ds.Tables(0).DefaultView_

Comment: Private Sub dgvsearchitem_CellDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvsearchitem.CellDoubleClick
        If dgvsearchitem.CurrentCell.RowIndex >= 0 Then
            Dim row As DataGridViewRow
            row = Me.dgvsearchitem.Rows(dgvsearchitem.CurrentCell.RowIndex)
            txtiname.Text = row.Cells("Iname").Value.ToString
            txtunit.Text = row.Cells("unitname").Value.ToString
            txtunitid.Text = row.Cells("unitcode").Value.ToString
            txticode.Text = row.Cells("icode").Value.ToString

        End If
    End Sub

Comment: @ravisharma this is a different error. Nothing to do with the Dataview approach. A DataView has the same columns of the DataTable from which has been created. Did you check if you have typed correctly the columns names? Did you try to put a space between _as[IName]_ in your query? Remove the square brackets around IName? Anyway, if the original problem has been solved then post a new question so more people can see your new problem and try to help you resolve it.

Comment: This is perplexing. The error message says that we don't have a column with the name requested and this shouldn't be possible. I would try to put a breakpoint on that procedure and when hit I would try to look at the names assigned to the datagridview columns, Perhaps this will shed some light on this error.

Comment: i tried but i think dataview doesnot support joins in the query thats why it is saying column not found.

Comment: @ravisharma Steve gave you perfect answer to **your question**. So you should accept it. If you have design issues - this is different question. You join your tables on the DB query and use Data View on the joined data. Another way to do all this is to load lists of models and use LINQ to display different subsets. This will make you join on the client

Comment: the answer is perfect . and sorting and filter is working perfectly even in using join but when i was not using the dataview approach my code for selecting data from datagridview was working fine but now i am not getting y my code is not working .

Comment: As I have said in precedence, I suggest you to post a new question with the details of the error and all the possible informations. If you continue to post comments here you cannot get a different (and perhaps better) point of view from mine and the few others that look at your problem from here.